# API Security with HMAC

Tags: api, security, authentication, backbone.js, hmac

I'm trying to build a Restful API with HMAC authentication. I've found a couple of articles (http://www.9bitstudios.com/2013/07/hmac-rest-api-security/) that have helped me get things started, but there are a few questions I have.

It seems like HMAC authentication relies on a private key which is used to generate a hash on the client side and used to re-create the same hash on the server-side for comparison.

But this raises the question of how the client knows the secret key. It would either have to be sent over the wire when the user logs in - or it would need to be already present in the client application.

It seems that if it gets sent over the wire on login - this opens up a security hole. But if it is already present in the client (a Backbone app in this case) someone could easily find it in the code.

My next question would be, if the secret key is not supposed to be sent over the wire, then how would it get to the client in the first place and be secure?

Comment: Yes sending the secure key over the wire would necessitate SSL and storing the secure key in the app does not stop someone from digging around and finding it.

Comment: You've hit the main difficulty of HMAC schemes. The client needs to embed the secret securely, which is generally not really possible.

Comment: Well this took me long to reply... but. What i've done is I've gone with including an SSL in order to transfer it. Thanks for the help! :)